# Can't solve options in Angular reponse

Tags: angular, typescript, api, response, status

I'm not able to set item in local storage when the response from backend is 200. Seems like it doesn't recognize the status of the request.

```
    options = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',   
      'Authorization': 'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem("access_token")
    }),
    observe: "response", // to display the full response
    responseType: "json"
  };


  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { 
   }
  
  authenticate(url, data, options) {
 
      this.http.post(environment.getBaseAddress() +url+'/', data, options).subscribe((data:any) =>  {
        if (data.status == 200) {
        localStorage.setItem("access_token", data['access_token']);
        console.log(data.status)
        }
        else this.router.navigateByUrl('something-else');
        })

      
    }
```

Comment: Also, if success portion of the subscription block is executing it implicitly means that your api call has been successful. You may not even need to worry about the status code in that case.

Comment: I can't share the access_token but the console.log(data.status) is not returning anything. Thank you for the insight. How could I handle the response success then in an if statement?

Comment: That's most likely coz there is no property called *status* on the data object that is returned by the api.

Comment: From what you have shared so far, on success you want to save the access token and on error you want to redirect to another route - is this correct?

Comment: ah ok gotcha. Is the options part done correctly you think? When I add observe: 'response'  in this.http.post(environment.getBaseAddress() +url+'/', data, {observe: "response") everything works fine. The issue starts when I add it inside the options.

Comment: Yes, correct. I'm trying to redirect based on the response from backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the *next* callback of the subscription block gets executed implies that your API call is successful. So you don't need to explicitly check the status code, you can alternatively do:

```
this.http.post(environment.getBaseAddress() +url+'/', data, options)
    .subscribe((data:any) => {
       localStorage.setItem("access_token", data['access_token']);
    }, (err) => {
       this.router.navigateByUrl('something-else');
    });
```

[More](https://angular.io/guide/observables#subscribing) on subscription callbacks.